# Confusing use of gradient in Pattern recognition and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, least-squares

I'm reading PRML and sometimes the gradient notation seems to be very confusing. In chapter 2, page 116, it is a a column vector:
[image]

And on Appendix E page 707, it is also a column vector:
[image]
However, in Chapter 3, during the derivation of least-square, page 141, it is now a row vector:
[image]

Can anyone clarify these confusing details for me? I have read some posts on the web, some of them says that the gradient is strictly a column vector, some says it depends on the calculation being carried out, some says it depends on the author, and I couldn't come up with a conclusive answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is exactly as stated in the question - gradient is a vector of partial derivatives, however treating it as column/row vector does not matter. People use orientation which is best for the particular use/derivation, the same applies to putting data points in data matrix row/column wise, defining linear projections as column/row vectors etc. Thus, the only answer is **it depends on the particular use**, you have to always check what kind of notation author uses. Why is that? Because it does not really matter, and for some calculations - row notation reduces amount of transpose operations needed, and for some - column notation helps. That's all.